# Digits range in randomizer

Tags: c++

I wrote program to pick random number for each half second in range of 1 to 1000000, and when i run it, it's drawing a number of maximum 5 digits. for example 32654 etc. Why it's not picking a higher numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){

    std::cout << "Losowa liczba z przedziału 1...100 \n";
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        int liczba = rand()%1000000 + 1;
        std::cout << liczba << std::endl;
        Sleep(200);
        i--;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because there's a flaw in your program.

Comment: There is no way we can help you without you providing your code.

Comment: If you are actually expecting an answer, you're going to have to post at least part of your current code.

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm new here

Comment: Did you purposely made it an infinite loop? Because you have incremented and decremented `i` at the same time.

Comment: @kubawich [here](http://ideone.com/Selkga), it's generating more than 5 digits

Comment: The standard library of your compiler probably produces only 15 bit positive random numbers. If you can, try using random number functions of C++11.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/:

> int rand (void);
>
> Generate random number
>
> Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX.

And from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/:

> RAND_MAX
>
> Maximum value returned by rand
>
> This macro expands to an integral constant expression whose value is the maximum value returned by the rand function.
>
> This value is library-dependent, but is guaranteed to be at least 32767 on any standard library implementation.

In your case, it appears that for the library you are using, `RAND_MAX` is probably defined as `32767`. And so `rand()%1000000 + 1` will never be larger than `32768`.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you used to generate random numbers "in range of 1 to 1000000" (i.e. `rand()%1000000 + 1`) can only work properly if the `rand()` itself is able to generate numbers in the same (or, better, much greater) range.

Apparently `rand()` on your platform does not generate such large numbers. Hence your approach doesn't work. Check the value `RAND_MAX` to make sure.